# R error number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I try to write a script that simulates 100 coin tosses with a certain probability of success, a starting capital and certain amount of capital to stop the game ('l'). It returns the probability of success. The code works, but it returns an error message. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

```
spins=100
SuccessVector=c()
ProbSuccess<-function(p, capital, l){
for(i in 1:spins){
cap=rep(capital,spins)
while(cap[i]>0 & cap[i]<l){
cap[i]=cap[i]+sample(c(-1,1), replace = TRUE, prob= c(1-p,p))
if(cap[i]==l){SuccessVector[i]=1}
else(SuccessVector[i]=0)
}
}
successes=length(SuccessVector[SuccessVector==1])/length(SuccessVector)
return(successes)
}
ProbSuccess(0.5,10,20)
```

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>
> warnings()
>
> Warning messages:
>   1: In cap[i] = cap[i] + sample(c(-1, 1), replace = TRUE,  ... :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help of sample():

> "For sample the default for size is the number of items inferred from
>   the first argument, so that sample(x) generates a random permutation
>   of the elements of x (or 1:x)."

That's why you get samples of size 2. You might want to use:

```
cap[i]=cap[i]+sample(c(-1,1), size=1 , replace = TRUE, prob= c(1-p,p))
```

Comment: No worries. Please also consider accepting the most helpful answers to your questions (see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).